# I want to make a file on a USB key that is FAT32 formatted invisible to windows users and shown to mac users

Tags: windows, macos, video

I have a client I am preparing a promotional USB key for.  The recipients of this key will be on a variety of operating systems.  we are targeting

- Windows XP+
- Mac OS X 10.6+

And we have a promotional video to be shown on all these systems. We cannot expect people to have a great variety of Codecs so I have packaged on the USB key a portable app of VLC and created an EXE that runs a bat file that plays the video in the portable VLC.  All that is good for windows users.  I've tested and am happy with this.

For MAC 10.6+ the H.264 codec the video is a [part of the Quicktime Player in 10.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3775)  So they can simply double click the video (or symlink, alias or hard link to that same file)

So that's the wind up.  Here's the pitch:

- On Windows I want users to double click an EXE file I've created
- On Mac I want users to double click either a video file (or symlink, alias or hard link to that same file)
- on either system I do not want users to see the other option so that they only have ONE thing they are asked to click.

This means I will have both:

- Windows-Only-File.exe
- Mac-Only-File.m4v

This means I need both:

1. A way to make a file on a FAT32 USB key show in Windows but not on a Mac
2. A way to make a file on a FAT32 USB key show in Mac but not on Windows
3. for all this to happen with default settings.  I cannot expect users to set any

I have #1 already.  Using the OS X dev tools I can set:

```
$ setfile -a V Windows-Only-File.exe
```

And that will hide it on Macs, while Windows machines will ignore the Mac only invisible prop and show the file.  I have tested this and it works.

It Seems trickier to pull off #2.  I have tried the right click in explorer and set file to hidden in windows thing but that hides it from BOTH OSes.  I have tried taking a hidden file and running:

```
$ setfile -a v Mac-Only-File.m4v
```

which removes the invisible flag but that removes hidden as well.

I am really out of ideas here.  Help???

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just provide the video in a format that virtually every computer can play, such as MPEG-1?

Comment: It may wall be easier but I'd still love this answered because the underlying issue here extends beyond my use case of video files.